# Aruba Access list redundant entries

Tags: access-control-list, aruba

I am using Aruba switches, and the configuration that I have been given to review has redundant entries in the ACL per below:

```
14 permit tcp 10.255.252.0/255.255.255.0 any eq ssh
15 permit tcp 10.255.253.0/255.255.255.0 any eq ssh
16 permit tcp 10.255.252.0/255.255.255.0 any eq ssh
```

would there be any reason to permit the same connection at two different times using the same protocol or is this just a simple mistake on the creation of the ACL. At this point nothing bad is happening to the network, just curious.

Answer (score 0):

Since ACL entries use a top-down, first-fit logic, later rules matching earlier ones are never used.

Sometimes it makes sense to (partially) duplicate earlier entries for a better overall logic, but in your case there's no reason for that.

In extreme, you could simplify that ACL down to

```
14 permit tcp 10.255.252.0/255.255.254.0 any eq ssh
```